# Flutter - geolocator, Error: No named parameter with the name 'forceAndroidLocationManager'

Tags: android, flutter, google-maps, geolocation

Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/geolocator-8.0.0/lib/geolocator.dart:54:11: Error: No named parameter with the name 'forceAndroidLocationManager'.
forceAndroidLocationManager: forceAndroidLocationManager);
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update the version to 8.0.1, its just updated to fix those error